# How to create a dictionary with key being value of a variable in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I mean to somehow translate this pseudo code into python3 code:
`dict(itemName = itemRecipe)`

What I have tried so far:

1)

```
allItems = [{}]
itemName = 'Pancake'
itemRecipe = ['Eggs', 'Flour']
allItems[0].update(dict(itemName = itemRecipe))
```

That yields me an array and with an object that has key called `'itemName'`, not `'Pancake'`.

2)

```
allItems = [{}]
itemName = 'Pancake'
itemRecipe = ['Eggs', 'Flour']
allItems[0].update(dict(locals()[itemName] = itemRecipe))
```

Throws me a `SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression`.

I am at a loss of what to do. Maybe anybody could help me there?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why not `allItems[itemName] = itemRecipe`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 allItems.update({itemName: itemRecipe})
```

but in your code allItems (btw camelcase is not in honor in Python) is a List so you should append it

```
 allItems.append({itemName: itemRecipe})
```

And if you want allItems to be a dict you can just do like

```
 allItems = {}
 allItems[itemName] = itemRecipe
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no attribute on `list` called `update`, but it is not clear what you are trying to achieve with that, but if what you want is a single-element list containing a dictionary whose key is `itemName`, and whose corresponding value is `itemRecipe`, you could simply let `allItems = [{itemName: itemRecipe}]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
allItems = [{}]
itemName = 'Pancake'
itemRecipe = ['Eggs', 'Flour']
allItems[0][itemName] = itemRecipe
print(allItems)
```

Comment: hope that is what you wanted

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a *lot* of list-of-dictionary manipulation, you can use the PLOD library:

```
from PLOD import PLOD

allItems = [{}]
itemName = 'Pancake'
itemRecipe = ['Eggs', 'Flour']

new_list = PLOD(allItems).\
    missingKey("itemName").\
    addKey("itemName", itemName).\
    addKey("itemRecipe", itemRecipe).\
    returnList()
```

This code locates all dictionary entries that do not have the "itemName" key. It then applies "itemName" and "itemRecipe" to that list of dictionaries.

The result:

```
>>> new_list
[{'itemRecipe': ['Eggs', 'Flour'], 'itemName': 'Pancake'}]
```

Or, to get fancy:

```
>>> print (PLOD(new_list).returnString())
[
    {itemName: 'Pancake', itemRecipe: ['Eggs', 'Flour']}
]
```

I only recommend this library if your code is filled with such manipulations. It is a lot of overhead if just doing this once.

This library can be found at PyPI and GitHub for python 2.7.x.